# Dropdown list not visible in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, browser

I have a dropdown list with options not visible in firefox but visble in both IE and Chrome. I have added the code snippet below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Mozilla Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<select id="product" name="product"  title="Product" tabindex="14" style="padding-top:1px!important;padding-bottom:1px!important;width:100px;>
  <option value="selectFruit" label="--Select--"></option>
  <option value="APP" label="Apple"></option>
  <option value="BAN" label="Banana"></option>
  <option value="GRA" label="Grapes"></option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anybody please help me with this issue.

Comment: Happened to me in Chrome - problem was I forgot to add the <!DOCTYPE html>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in firefox. (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=40545#c11)

I'm assuming you've tried adding the label as the content of the option element?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Mozilla Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<select id="product" name="product"  title="Product" tabindex="14" style="padding-top:1px!important;padding-bottom:1px!important;width:100px;>
  <option value="selectFruit" label="--Select--"></option>
  <option value="APP" label="Apple">Apple</option>
  <option value="BAN" label="Banana">Banana</option>
  <option value="GRA" label="Grapes">Grapes</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It might work but I am getting the html content of options from a backend code so it would be my last resort.

Comment: @naXa That's a fair point, but it's still unresolved, and available to be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

You have to write value in

```
<option value="APP" label="Apple">Apple</option>
```

Comment: It might work but I am getting the html content of options from a backend code so it would be my last resort.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old unresolved issue in Firefox but assuming that you can use jQuery, sharing a quick workaround that did the job for me. Multiple select elements, like the one given below, were used in my aspx page -

```
<select id="cbType" runat="server" class="form-control"
    title="<%$ Resources: Something %>">
    <option value="0" selected="selected" label="<%$ Resources: Option1 %>" runat="server"></option>
    <option value="1" label="<%$ Resources: Option2 %>" runat="server"></option>
    <option value="2" label="<%$ Resources: Option3 %>" runat="server"></option>
    <option value="3" label="<%$ Resources: Option4 %>" runat="server"></option>
    <option value="4" label="<%$ Resources: Option5 %>" runat="server"></option>
</select>
```

Now just call below method from jQuery(document).ready().

```
function fixFirefoxDropdownIssue() {
    jQuery('select option').each(function() {
        jQuery(this).text(jQuery(this).attr('label'));
    });
}
```

It basically sets the inner text of option to the value specified by label attribute. You can change the jQuery selector to make it more specific, if required.

This way, you don't have to change any server side data tags. Have tested this in Firefox 40.0.3.